# Which integral is bigger

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there an efficient way of knowing which integral will be evaluated to a bigger number?

$$\text{(I)}  ~~~\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{e^x + e^{-\frac1x}} ~ dx ~~~~~~~~~~ \text{or} ~~~~~~~~~~ \text{(II)} ~~~\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{e^x + e^{-\frac1x}} ~ dx$$

If the $\LaTeX$ is too small, then this reads for (I)- The integral from $0$ to $\infty$ of:
**numerator:** $\cos x$
**denominator:** $e^{x} + e^{- \frac1x} $.  In words: (($e$ to the power of $x$) $+$ ($e$ to the power of $- 1/x$))
The same goes for the second integral (II), but just $\sin x$ instead of $\cos x$ in the numerator.

I thought just to try and solve for the explicit values, but that does not turn quite good, the only thing that came to my mind is the Feynman's method for integration:
$ \text{(1)}$ :

$$ J(b) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{e^x + e^{-\frac1x}} \cdot e^{-b (e^x + e^{-\frac1x})} ~ dx $$

Then differentiating with respect to $b$:

$$ J'(b) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{ \partial}{\partial b} \left ( \frac{\cos x}{e^x + e^{-\frac1x}} \cdot e^{-b (e^x + e^{-\frac1x})} \right ) ~ dx  = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{e^x + e^{-\frac1x}} \cdot e^{-b (e^x + e^{-\frac1x})}  \cdot ( e^x + e^{-\frac1x} )~ dx \\= \int_0^{\infty} {\cos x} \cdot e^{-b (e^x + e^{-\frac1x})} ~ dx$$

But then I got stuck as this is too complicated to intigrate by hand, and I don't think there is a closed form for this.

---

*Notes:*

- This is not a question of a specific course, nor a homework (just a question I wanted to ask out of curiosity), so any method will do *except* for giving an output using a computer (You can use it to approximate stuff but don't push it into Desmos)
- I don't have a context for this problem unfortunately, I tried to search the web as well and did not find this exact question, [I only found this video by flammable maths](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bx5JVL1vCA0&ab_channel=FlammableMaths) - however it is a finite bound and not the exact functions.

Comment: I expect (I) to be larger.  The denominator is increasing rapidly.  $\cos(x) > \sin(x)$ for $x near $0$, which is the most important part of the integral.

Comment: @GEdgar By graphing this you are correct but, the function inside integral (I) also "enters" the negative zone earlier than (II).

Comment: and the similar integrals with denominator only $e^x$ both evaluate to $1/2$.